# Python & Beautifulsoup 4 - Scraping code optimization

Tags: python, optimization, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to scrape multiple websites for specific products and I'm sure there is a way to optimize my code. As of right now, the code does it's job but this is really not the Pythonic way to go about it(I am a Python novice so please excuse my lack of knowledge).

The goal of this program is to get the prices of the products from the URLs provided and write them to a .csv file. Each website has a different structure, but I am always using the same 3 websites. This is an example of my current code:

```
import requests
import csv
import io
import os
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

timeanddate=datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

folder_path = 
'my_folder_path'
file_name = 'product_prices_'+timeanddate+'.csv'
full_name = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)

with io.open(full_name, 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as file:
 writer = csv.writer(file)
writer.writerow(["ProductTitle", "Website1", "Website2", "Website3"])

#---Product 1---
#Website1 price
website1product1 = requests.get('website1product1URL')
website1product1Data = BeautifulSoup(website1product1.text, 'html.parser')
website1product1Price = website1product1Data.find('div', attrs={'class': 'price-final'}).text.strip()
print(website1product1Price)

#Website2 price
website2product1 = requests.get('website2product1URL')
website2product1Data = BeautifulSoup(website2product1.text, 'html.parser')
website2product1Price = website2product1Data.find('div', attrs={'class': 'price_card'}).text.strip()
print(website2product1Price)

#Website3 price
website3product1 = requests.get('website3product1URL')
website3product1Data = BeautifulSoup(website3product1.text, 'html.parser')
website3product1Price = website3product1Data.find('strong', attrs={'itemprop': 'price'}).text.strip()
print(website3product1Price)

writer.writerow(["ProductTitle", website1product1Price, website2product1Price, website3product1Price])

file.close()
```

It saves the ProductTitles and Prices to a .csv in this format and I'd like to keep this format:

```
#Header
ProductTitle Website1 Website2 Website3
#Scraped data
Product1     $23      $24      $52
```

This is manageable for a few products, but I'd like to have hundreds and copying the same lines of code and changing variable names is confusing, tedious and is bound to be riddled with human error.

Can I create a function that takes 3 URLs as arguments and outputs the website1product1Price, website2product1Price and website2product1Price, and call that function once per product? Can it then be wrapped in a loop to go through a list of URLs and still keep the original formatting?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this could be a solution for you?
Admitting you have an array of dict for your product:

```
products = [
    {
      'name': 'product1',
      'url1': 'https://url1',
      'url2': 'https://url2',
      'url3': 'https://url3'
    }
]
```

Your code could be something like this:

```
import requests
import csv
import io
import os
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_product_prices(product):

    #---Product 1---
    #Website1 price
    website1product1 = requests.get(product['url1'])
    website1product1Data = BeautifulSoup(website1product1.text, 'html.parser')
    website1product1Price = website1product1Data.find('div', attrs={'class': 'price-final'}).text.strip()

    #Website2 price
    website2product1 = requests.get(product['url2'])
    website2product1Data = BeautifulSoup(website2product1.text, 'html.parser')
    website2product1Price = website2product1Data.find('div', attrs={'class': 'price_card'}).text.strip()

    #Website3 price
    website3product1 = requests.get(product['url3'])
    website3product1Data = BeautifulSoup(website3product1.text, 'html.parser')
    website3product1Price = website3product1Data.find('strong', attrs={'itemprop': 'price'}).text.strip()

    return website1product1Price, website2product1Price, website3product1Price

timeanddate=datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

folder_path = 
'my_folder_path'
file_name = 'product_prices_'+timeanddate+'.csv'
full_name = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)

with io.open(full_name, 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["ProductTitle", "Website1", "Website2", "Website3"])

    for product in products:
        price1, price2, price3 = get_product_prices(product)
        write.writerow(product['name'], price1, price2, price3)

file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed. Modified it a bit, included error handling and it's good to go. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function and pass everything as parameter like `url`, `tag_name` , `attribute_name` and `attribute_value`.see if this help.

```
def price_text(url_text,ele_tag,ele_attr,attrval):
 website1product1 = requests.get(url_text)
 website1product1Data = BeautifulSoup(website1product1.text, 'html.parser')
 website1product1Price=website1product1Data.find("'" + ele_tag + "'", attrs="{'" + ele_attr + "': '" + attrval + "'}").text.strip()
 print(website1product1Price)

website1product1Price=price_text("url","div","class","price-final")
website1product2Price=price_text("url","div","class","price_card")
website1product3Price=price_text("url","strong","itemprop","price")
```

Comment: This is quite useful, however I went with the above answer. I appreciate your effort - thank you very much.